# Remove duplicate object key values

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, key

I am creating an HTML form select element using the following array of objects.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Showing Now Review
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Interstellar
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => The Conjuring 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Django Unchained
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Captain America: Civil War
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Dallas Buyers Club
        )
)
```

This is the contents of an array named $reviewTitles.

I then want to foreach through this, and display the first letter of each title in the select.

I have achieved this so far using the following code:

```
foreach($reviewTitles as $key => $value) { 
  $fullTitle = $reviewTitles[$key]->post_title; 
  $firstLetter = substr($fullTitle, 0, 1); ?>

<option value="<?php echo($firstLetter); ?>" <?php echo($_POST[ 'cboTitle']=="<?php echo($firstLetter); ?>" ? "selected='selected'": "")?>>
  <?php echo($firstLetter); ?>
</option>

<?php } ?>
```

However, with this code, if there is a title with the same letter as previously shown, it will display again in the dropdown. So for example, two D's are shown at the moment in the dropdown.

I am wondering how I can remove any duplicate entries from the final list in the select element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the first letter as the option value? Use something else so you don't have a problem with duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

First:

You dont seem to understand what the foreach loop is doing. The `$value` will in fact be each object in turn

```
<?php
foreach($reviewTitles as $key => $value) { 
    $firstLetter = substr($value->post_title, 0, 1); 
    $sel = $_POST['cboTitle'] == $firstLetter ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option $sel value='$firstLetter'>$firstLetter</option>";
} 
?>
```

Now to stop duplicates being printed, remember the first letters in an array and then check if the new firstletter is already in the array

```
<?php
$f_letters = array();
foreach($reviewTitles as $key => $value) { 
    $firstLetter = substr($value->post_title, 0, 1); 
    if ( !in_array($firstLetter, $f_letters) ) {
        $f_letters[] = $firstLetter;
        $sel = $_POST['cboTitle'] == $firstLetter ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo "<option $sel value='$firstLetter'>$firstLetter</option>";
    }
} 
?>
```

But I cannot for the life of me work out what you are actually trying to do here. This may well prove to be useless to you in reality